# How do I require Gosu with IronRuby?

Tags: ruby, static, shared-libraries, native, libgosu

I tried to require Gosu's .so file, but it said something about "expecting assembly". 
I assumed that IronRuby will support library files which aren't written in dot net, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

IronRuby doesn't support libraries that use native extensions. In order to use these with IronRuby, the extension should be ported to C# first.